# Number of ordered 3-tuples of subsets such that intersection of any two is empty

Tags: combinatorics

Let $X$ be a set with $2021$ elements. Consider the set
$$\mathcal{S} = \left\{(A,B,C): A,B,C\subseteq X,~ A\cap B = \emptyset, ~B\cap C = \emptyset,~ \text{ and }C\cap A = \emptyset\right\}.$$

Then what is the cardinality of the set $\mathcal{S}$?

> I can only think of the following cases:
>
> - $\{(\emptyset,\emptyset,\emptyset)\}$
> - $\left|\{(\emptyset,\emptyset,C): \emptyset \neq C\subseteq X\}\right| = 2^{2021}-1$. Since we can permute these sets, the total number will be $\left(2^{2021}-1\right) \times 3$.

These cases become very tedious and look complicated. Any help/hint will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps try counting the functions $f : \{1,...,2021\}  \to \{0,...,3\}$?

Comment: The total number of functions will be $4^{2021}$, but I am not getting how it will help.

Comment: Think about which set, if any, the element $1$ is in. What about $2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X = \{1,2,\ldots,2021\}$. Let us count the ordered $3$-tuples $(A,B,C)$ such that intersection of any two is empty.

Following the hints provided in the comment, we note that for every $n\le 2021$, we have the following choices for $n$.

- $n \in A,~ n\notin B,\text{ and } n \notin C$
- $n \notin A,~ n\in B,\text{ and } n \notin C$
- $n \notin A,~ n\notin B,\text{ and } n \in C$ and
- $n \notin A,~ n\notin B,\text{ and } n \notin C$.

Therefore, the number of elements in the set $\mathcal{S}$ is $4^{2021}$.

Comment: Equivalently let $D=X \backslash (A \cup B\cup C)$ so each of the $2021$ elements of $X$ will be in exactly one of the $4$ of $A,B,C,D$